Is it possible to build wpewebkit into one single process app with minimum source code change?
As I'm trying to build WPEWebKit1 to a close source custom OS
It seems there're at least three processes needed if I'm trying to build a minimum browser from it

the app it self
the web-process
the network process

However, the OS I'm trying to run browser on don't provide multi-process APIs to me.
So I wonder is it possible to make minimum changes to WPEWebKit source code to make it work within just one single process the whole time

so in conclution, can I strip the IPC part of WPEWebKit and still make it work, has anyone tried this before

Any advices would be much helpful
